# Best way of showing Stream Data in Android Listview

Tags: android, performance, listview, stream, baseadapter

We are trying to show a table data on a listview.  The data consists of 8 columns and around 50 rows.
In one second period approximatelly 8 update data comes.
(ie:update row2-column5 to something.)
Every time a new data comes, we are updating the dedicated cells and we call `datasetchanged()` of the adapter 
and this causes some performance and scrolling problems.

My question is:
**What is the best way of showing stream data in Android using standard widgets?**

Comment: @dziobas:i have used BaseAdapter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try refreshing only the items that need updating. To do so, you will need the position of the data in the listview.

```
private void updateData(int position)
{
    int firstItem = listView1.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    View view = listView1.getChildAt(position - firstItem);
    TextView tv = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    tv.setText("Example Text");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would either write my own Cursor and plug it into CursorAdapter and an AdapterView, or...just use the [MatrixCursor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/MatrixCursor.html).  The MatrixCursor allows you to add new "row".  Then you can call `onChange()` to notify the View your data has changed.